# Button action inside collectionview cell - Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child-

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have a uibutton inside a collectionview cell. Users can like their posts with this button. But I got these errors : 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' and 'Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child'

For collection view button action, I did this

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath) as! AdCell

    cell.likeOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.likeOutlet.addTarget(self,
                              action: #selector(self.likeButt),
                              for: .touchUpInside)
```

and this is IBAction in main viewcontroller

```
@IBAction func likeButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if PFUser.current() != nil {

        let currUser = PFUser.current()!

        let query = PFQuery(className: LIKES_CLASS_NAME)
        query.whereKey(LIKES_CURR_USER, equalTo: currUser)
        query.whereKey(LIKES_AD_LIKED, equalTo: adObj)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {

                if objects!.count == 0 
                {

                    let likeObj = PFObject(className: LIKES_CLASS_NAME)

                    likeObj[LIKES_CURR_USER] = currUser
                    likeObj[LIKES_AD_LIKED] = self.adObj
                    likeObj.saveInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
                        if error == nil {
                            AdCell.appearance().likeOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ad_liked"), for: .normal)
                            self.hideHUD()


                            self.adObj.incrementKey(ADS_LIKES, byAmount: 1)


                            if self.adObj[ADS_LIKED_BY] != nil {
                                var likedByArr = self.adObj[ADS_LIKED_BY] as! [String]
                                likedByArr.append(currUser.objectId!)
                                self.adObj[ADS_LIKED_BY] = likedByArr
                            } else {
                                var likedByArr = [String]()
                                likedByArr.append(currUser.objectId!)
                                self.adObj[ADS_LIKED_BY] = likedByArr
                            }
                            self.adObj.saveInBackground()


                            let sellerPointer = self.adObj[ADS_SELLER_POINTER] as! PFUser
                            let pushStr = "\(PFUser.current()![USER_USERNAME]!) liked your ad: \(self.adObj[ADS_TITLE]!)"

                            let data = [ "badge" : "Increment",
                                         "alert" : pushStr,
                                         "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
                            ]
                            let request = [
                                "someKey" : sellerPointer.objectId!,
                                "data" : data
                                ] as [String : Any]

                            PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "push", withParameters: request as [String : Any], block: { (results, error) in
                                if error == nil {
                                    print ("\nPUSH SENT TO: \(sellerPointer[USER_USERNAME]!)\nMESSAGE: \(pushStr)\n")
                                } else {
                                    print ("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                }
                            })



                            // Save Activity
                            let activityClass = PFObject(className: ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME)
                            activityClass[ACTIVITY_CURRENT_USER] = sellerPointer
                            activityClass[ACTIVITY_OTHER_USER] = PFUser.current()!
                            activityClass[ACTIVITY_TEXT] = pushStr
                            activityClass.saveInBackground()


                            // error on saving like
                        } else {
                            self.simpleAlert("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                            self.hideHUD()
                        }})


                    // 3. UNLIKE THIS AD :(
                } else {
                    var likeObj = PFObject(className: LIKES_CLASS_NAME)
                    likeObj = objects![0]
                    likeObj.deleteInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
                        if error == nil {
                            AdCell.appearance().likeOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ad_no_like"), for: .normal)
                            self.hideHUD()


                            self.adObj.incrementKey(ADS_LIKES, byAmount: -1)


                            var likedByArr = self.adObj[ADS_LIKED_BY] as! [String]
                            likedByArr = likedByArr.filter { $0 != currUser.objectId! }
                            self.adObj[ADS_LIKED_BY] = likedByArr

                            self.adObj.saveInBackground()


                            //                                let likesNr = self.adObj[ADS_LIKES] as! Int
                            //                            self.likeLabel.text = "\(likesNr)"

                        } else {
                            self.simpleAlert("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                            self.hideHUD()
                        }})
                }


                // error in query
            } else {
                self.simpleAlert("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                self.hideHUD()
            }}

    } else {
        showLoginAlert("You need to login")
    }
}
```

In another page, this function works well. but here gives error. What am I missing ?

EDIT :

Firstly this line gave error **if objects!.count == 0**

I replaced this line with **if objects?.count == 0**  and worked

But now **likeObj = objects![0]** gives error

When I write **objects?[0]** instead of **objects![0]** again, I'm getting these errors

**Value of optional type 'PFObject?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'PFObject'** and **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint and step through in debug to find the exact line that is causing the error.

Comment: @DonMag I updated. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @UchihaSasuke, My first question is, You are creating `PFObject`, but assigning the value to `likeObj` from `objects` array immediately at next line. So, Is there any specific reason to create `PFObject` and replace with `objects` array value?

Comment: Also your array `objects` holds `PFObject` objects?